# ASP.NET MVC: shortcut for Response.Write and String.Format

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-4.0

I've found a pattern in my Views like this:

```
<% if (someCondition)
   {
       Response.Write(string.Format("Foo {0}, Bar {1} Baz {2}.", userName, someCounter, someDate)); }
   else
   {
       Response.Write(string.Format("Foo is {0}.", bar));
   } 
%>
```

The basic pattern of `if...else` with a bunch of repeated `Response.Write(string.Format())` for each condition. The idea here is not re-usability in where a partial view or helper method would be appropriate, but rather a shortcut that would ideally look like `Response.WriteFormattedString()`.

The question here is around DRY and `Response.Write(string.Format())`. Are there better, or more concise ways to . Consider that HTML encoding would be a nice feature to include, perhaps as a boolean to a method call of some kind (extension method on `Html`?.

The goal is to try to avoid multiple render blocks `<%: %>` and `<%= %>`.

Is there an obvious extension method that I'm missing?
Do you have an extension method that you rely on to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<%: Html.Greeting(Model) %>
```

...Where `Html.Greeting` is a method you write which accepts your page model.